# Add a second click function to a selected polygon feature in Openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to add a click function to a selected feature which will delete this selected feature in OpenLayers 4.

> ```
>   var Delete = {
>     init: function() {
>       this.select = new ol.interaction.Select({});
>       map.addInteraction(this.select);
>
>       this.setEvents();
>     },
>     setEvents: function() {
>       var selectedFeatures = this.select.getFeatures();
>       selectedFeatures.on('add', function(event) {
>         var feature = event.element;
>         // delete the layer/feature on clicking again
>         feature.on('click',function(e){
>             vector.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
>             selectedFeatures.clear(); 
>         });
>         console.log(feature);
>
>       });
>     },
>     setActive: function(active) {
>       this.select.setActive(active);
>     }
>   };
>   Delete.init();
> ```

But this second click function is never triggered. Is there any other way to attach a click event handler to the selected feature in OL4 and then remove that handler if it is unselected.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for better answer?

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004561/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-on-openlayers-4

"There is no click event registered for a feature ol.Feature object. But click event is present for ol.Map. Use forEachFeatureAtPixel method to get all the features at a pixel and compare it with the feature for which you want to add a listener."

Comment: @notkilroy I have many different types of features in the map like polygons, markers, lines and circles. If I have to attach different click function for each then i need to handle everthing in a single click function.? Like in this code snippet.?
`map.on('click', function (e) {
   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function (feature) {return feature;});
   if (feature) {
// check if the feature is a polygon or a circle or a marker etc..
// get the property and execute the desired action
   }
});`

Comment: yes. that's correct.